# will the index be stored with other column? [mariadb]

Tags: database, indexing

there is a table.

**tb_a**

```
seq(pk) | name | type | regist_time
```

and there is 5 record.

```
seq | name | type | regist_time  
-------------------------------
1   |  B   | 200  | 2019-05-03
-------------------------------
2   |  A   | 300  | 2019-05-03
-------------------------------
3   |  E   | 100  | 2019-05-03
-------------------------------
4   |  D   | 100  | 2019-05-03
-------------------------------
5   |  C   | 100  | 2019-05-03
```

and add index name

```
index(name)
```

****QUESTION****
did name be stored alone? like below:

```
name
----
 A
----
 B
----
 C
----
 D
----
 E
```

or be stored with other columns?

```
seq | name | type | regist_time  
-------------------------------
2   |  A   | 300  | 2019-05-03
-------------------------------
1   |  B   | 200  | 2019-05-03
-------------------------------
5   |  C   | 100  | 2019-05-03
-------------------------------
4   |  D   | 100  | 2019-05-03
-------------------------------
3   |  E   | 100  | 2019-05-03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an index on a column in most modern DB systems, you can think of the index as only containing the value of the column and a pointer to related row. It does not contain a the content of any other column (it is a bit more complex than this, but for our purposes this is good enough).

If you have a query that use the index , and retrieves multiple columns from the DB, the system will pull the 'name' from the index and then use the pointer to find the correct rows. It then fetches the actual rows from the table to find and return all the other data